# replacing the content of a jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable

I have a desktop application in swing with NetBeans IDE
 the application has a `JTable` that displays 
 data from a lucene search operation.

Any time a new search is made ,
 the table appends the new search results to 
 the previous search result. What I 
want is for the table to replace any exiting 
search results with the new search results. In order 
words for the table to refresh and display the new
 search results.

Any suggestions available

this is the code snippet for the datamodel

```
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private Vector<Vector<String>> dataList = new Vector<>();
     private String[] header = { "ID","SUBJECT","LETTTER FROM","LETTER DATE","DATE RECEIED",
                                  "REMARKS","DATE DISPATCHED","DESTINATION OFFICE"};



    public Vector<Vector<String>> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }

    public void setDataList(Vector<Vector<String>> dataList) {       
        this.dataList = dataList;
        fireTableDataChanged(); 
    }

    public void setHeader(String[] header) {
        this.header = header;
    }

    public String[] getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return header.length;
    }

    @Override
   public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return header[col];
   }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
    return dataList.get(row).get(col);
    }

}
```

this code passes the search result to the data model class

```
private void searchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    try {

        searchField = searchTextField.getText();
        if(!searchField.isEmpty())
        {                
       matrix = dbs.searchDatabase(searchField + "*");
       myModel.setDataList(matrix);

        }

    } catch (CorruptIndexException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GNSSJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (LockObtainFailedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GNSSJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GNSSJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }             
}
```

Comment: Please post some part of your code

Comment: Do a model refresh beforehand.

Comment: What model have you used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your table model is in this way,

```
class AllTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    // Suppose this is the data list table is using,
    List<TableData> tableData = new ArrayList<TableData>();

    // Override methods goes here.

    public void setTableData(List<TableData> tableData) {
        this.tableData = tableData;
        fireTableDataChanged();
}  
}
```

Now, set the new data to the list using the table model instance.

```
 allTableModel.setTableData(/* Set new search results to the list.*/);
```

Comment: The table model should really encapsulate that, and fire the appropriate event.

Comment: Yes, much better. I would prefer if it made a defensive copy of the list, but that's an implementation detail. +1.

Comment: and or with StructureChanged (about column models), but depends of, notice custom renderers and editors can go away after data & structure changed, required to add those notifiers again

Comment: I have the datamodel and pass the search result to it as in your format but get the same result. I have added the code snippets.

Comment: @faisalabdulai Did you debugged the code? If not just check the results after the call and see whether the results are same or not.

Comment: finaly found the bug , one array list was created for the lucene search result when a new search is made, the list is updated by appendeding new data to the existing data in the list. To fix the bug, I use the list.clear() method to flush all existing data before adding the new data to the list. thank you all for the suggestions

Comment: @mKorbel a structural change is unlikely here (most probably, the model has one fixed property of the item, per column) And tableColumns (and with them their custom-set properties like sizes, renderers, editors) are replaced only on a structureChanged _not_ on a dataChanged. Just a reminder :-)